# getting method not allowed exception when send ajax with post method

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

i develop web application with laravel 5.2 , i try to send an array with ajax to my controller , the request sent but after that i saw the error :405 method not allowed , i searched many times but this problem didn't solve :
my ajax code is :

```
          // send array of stream checkbox to controller
             $('#json-btn').click(function () {

            var input = $("form input:checkbox");

            var stream = [];
            $.each($(input), function(){
                stream.push($(this).val());
            });

            var jstream = JSON.stringify(stream);
            var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

            $.ajax({
                url: '/ajaxGet/',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN , jstream:jstream},
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

my route is :

```
Route::post('ajaxGet', 'ajaxController@getRequest');
```

my controller is :

```
    <?php

     namespace App\Http\Controllers;

     use Illuminate\Http\Request;

     use App\Http\Requests;

    class ajaxController extends Controller
    {
          public function getRequest(Request $request)
          {
              echo $request['jstream'];
          }
    }
```

and finally this is my form :

```
         {!! Form::open(array('id' => 'trailer-form')) !!}
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

                <table  dir="rtl">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>quality</th>
                        <th>link</th>
                        <th>steram</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            {!! Form::select('quality[]', array('noQuality'=>'select...','64p'=>'64p','144p'=>'144p','240p'=>'240p','360p'=>'360p','480p'=>'480p','720p'=>'720p', '1080p'=>'1080p'), null , ['class'=> 'form-control lns' , 'id' => 'quality-input']) !!}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {!! Form::text('downLoadLink[]',null,['class' => 'form-control ln' , 'id' => 'down-input']) !!}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {!! Form::checkbox('stream[]','false',null,['class' => 'form-control' , 'id' => 'streamCheck' , 'onchange' => 'createAlerts(this)']) !!}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus gs"></i>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                {!! Form::submit('json create',['class' => 'btn btn-success' , 'id' => 'json-btn']) !!}
                {!! Form::close() !!}
```

please help me to solve this problem thank you so very much :)

Comment: You'll need to set CORS headers in your web server configuration

Comment: thanks for your answer , i use wamp server , CORS is php extension or apache ?

Comment: Hey - it's a security specification. You need to set the appropriate headers for it - google it

Comment: please check the method in your routes file, is it GET?

Comment: hi :) , this is my route " Route::post('ajaxGet', 'ajaxController@getRequest'); , my method is post same as ajax method

Comment: @Robbie , i set the headers but still not working

Comment: can you share your Debugger screen shot, so I can look into that where is sending your AJAX request?